# Why postgres database using double buffer method?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres using double buffer for performing operation. But why? What is the need for it.
please explain .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are referring to shared buffers and the kernel cache, both of which cache PostgreSQL data since PostgreSQL uses buffered I/O rather than direct I/O.

The reason is probably that PostgreSQL aims to be very portable, so using buffered I/O with its higher level of abstraction from the system was the easier choice.

There is definitely [a desire to change that](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20210223100344.llw5an2aklengrmn@alap3.anarazel.de), but that is a big project, if it ever comes to pass.